# MS Exchange Transport Rules - Using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, exchange-server

I have tried researching and I've done quite of bit of trial and error, nothing is working.

GOAL: Any email sent to `ABC@mydomain.com` when the Subject field contains "`MT5`", redirect the message to `DEF@mydomain.com`.

ISSUE: This rule only seems to work when "`MT5`" is the entire subject line.  It does not work when it is part of the subject line such as "`New Email MT5 Sent`".

PROCESS: I'm using Exchange Management Console > Organization Configuration > Hub Transport > Transport Rules.  I have tested this by adding with quotes, without quotes, with single quotes, and even some regex (which doesn't seem like it should be necessary considering the transport rule says "when the Subject field CONTAINS" but I figured it was worth a shot).  The regex I tried is as follows:

```
$MT5^
^MT5$
\$MT5\^
\^MT5\$
```

Nothing I have tried has worked.  Can someone please help?

Comment: Try with `.*MT5.*`

Comment: Tried that. no luck.   :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work finally.  Here is what I ended up with...

```
Apply rule to messages
sent to 'ABC@mydomain.com'
and when the Subject field matches '(mt5)*'
redirect to 'DEF@mydomain.com'
```

The key is using the selection in the Edit Transport Rule wizard "when the Subject field matches text patters" and using (mt5)* for the pattern.  It seems if regex is to be used, you have to use "pattern".

**UPDATE:**  It turns out that didn't work exactly right, it was capturing too many emails.  I used this new solution along with an earlier suggestion and it seems to be working now.  Here is what seemed to work after fine-tuning:

```
Apply rule to messages
sent to 'ABC@mydomain.com'
and when the Subject field matches '.*MT5.*'
redirect to 'DEF@mydomain.com'
```